# How to read a external directory in android?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to read different value folder without any android  help?

Normally Language change to another language our application change relevant folder in res directory.

Comment: Can you elaborate , this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is partially true. If you have for e.g. res/values and res/values-fr, then when you will have French locale, resources from "values-fr" will be used, otherwise default one from "values for all other cases".

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

If you have any special files, that you want to include in your apk (also organized within any sub-folders) you can use assets folder, like:

```
AssetManager manager = getAssets();
manager.open("subFolder/file.txt");
```

for file that is in assets/subFolder/file.txt